# In which modern-day location did the historical battles of Bagrevand happen?

Tags: geography, armenia

Wikipedia names at least two "battles of Bagrevand",

- [In 371 between Persia and allied Roman-Armenian forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Bagrevand_(371))
- [In 775 between the Abbasid Caliphate and rebelling Armenian princes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Bagrevand)

both occuring in the "plains of Bagrevand", but it did not name the modern day location of these battles. "[Bagrevand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagrevand)" itself has a Wikipedia entry, but it is only described as "a region of the old kingdom Greater Armenia" without mentioning any specific location. Where approximately is the historical plains of Bagrevand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Khorenatsi 3, 37, that was a field of Dzirav which now is in Turkey, il Agri, in the upper reaches of Eastern Euphrates (aka Murat River).

Both Khorenatsi and Buzand mention the mountain of Npat nearby. Unfortunately, I was (still) unable to find out where exactly this mountain (Npat, or Npatakan, or Nifagis, or Tapa-Sheid) is located.

[This page](http://wikimapia.org/30887073/Battle-Of-Dzirav) (without mentioning any source) points at [39°36'30"N 43°28'37"E](https://www.google.com/maps/place/39%C2%B036'30.0"N+43%C2%B028'37.0"E) which is between the villages of [Bayramyazi](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayramyaz%C4%B1,_Ta%C5%9Fl%C4%B1%C3%A7ay), [Kumluca](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumluca,_Ta%C5%9Fl%C4%B1%C3%A7ay) and [Kumlubucak](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumlubucak,_Ta%C5%9Fl%C4%B1%C3%A7ay) in Agri il.

Sources:

- [Faustus of Byzantium (aka Buzand)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faustus_of_Byzantium) "History of Armenia" ([English translation](http://www.attalus.org/armenian/pbtoc.html)), Book V, Ch. 4;
- [Movses Khorenatsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movses_Khorenatsi) "History of Armenia" ([wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Armenia_(book))), Book III, Ch. 37

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain which works you're referring to by "Khorenaci" and "Buzand"?

Comment: @user69715 Added.